# PHP Loop two arrays if index of one is last rewind array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two arrays. The first array is names and it has 5 names. The second array is groups and it has 3 groups. I want to loop through both of the arrays and set each index name to the index group. If the group index finishes I want to restart the second array.

I tried reseting the group index to 0 if it reaches the last item but it doesn't work.

```
$names = [
  'John',
  'Jane',
  'George',
  'Jim',
  'Jack'
];

$groups = [
  '1',
  '2',
  '3'
];

foreach ($names as $index => $name) {
   $result = "The student: " . $name . " belongs to the: " .$groups[$index]. "group" ;
   echo ($result);
   echo "<br>";
   echo "<br>";
}
```

When it reaches the fourth name item, the group item should be 1. Is there a way to do such think?

Expected outcome

```
John - 1

Jane - 2

George - 3

Jim - 1

Jack - 2
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you share your expected output here

Answer (score 6):

We assume that the array is numerically indexed (starting from 0), and that there are no indexes that are skipped (i.e. the `$group` array is *always* defined as `range(1, $n);`).

Then you can use the modulus operator `%` against the length of that array, as shown below.

```
foreach ($names as $index => $name) {
   $result = "The student: " . $name . " belongs to group " .$groups[$index % count($groups)]. ".\n";
   echo $result;
}
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/LmYRk

Answer (score 4):

You can modulo `%` the groups indexing.

`$groups[$index % sizeOf($groups)]`

```
<?php
$names = [
  'John',
  'Jane',
  'George',
  'Jim',
  'Jack'
];

$groups = [
  '1',
  '2',
  '3'
];

foreach ($names as $index => $name) {
   $result = "The student: " . $name . " belongs to the: " .$groups[$index%sizeOf($groups)]. "group" ;
   echo ($result);
   echo "<br>";
   echo "<br>";
}
```

result: https://3v4l.org/LnOHAK

```
The student: John belongs to the: 1group<br><br>The student: Jane belongs to the: 2group<br><br>The student: George belongs to the: 3group<br><br>The student: Jim belo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this! In this code if you add a new group no have be problem.

```
<?php

$names = [
  'John',
  'Jane',
  'George',
  'Jim',
  'Jack'
];

$groups = [
  '1',
  '2',
  '3'
];

foreach ($names as $index => $name) {

   $result = "The student: " . $name . " belongs to the: " .$groups[$index % count($groups)]. "group" ;
   echo ($result);
   echo "<br>";
   echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any kind of array

```
$names = [
  'John',
  'Jane',
  'George',
  'Jim',
  'Jack'
];

global $groups;

$groups = [
  '1',
  '2',
  '3'
];

$newArr = array_combine(
            $names, 
              array_merge(
                  $groups,
                  array_map(
                    function($v){
                      global $groups;
                      return $groups[$v%count($groups)]; 
                    }, 
                   array_keys(array_diff_key($names, $groups))
                 )
              )
          );
```